# how can i execute command who have input

Tags: linux, bash

i want to execute a python script who have 3 inputs  .

so i want to execute the script in the shell by one line command and pass him the inputs values .

i have seen one solution to do that but it works just if i have only one input .
the command is like :

```
$ echo "params input" | python myscript.py
```

the issue is the command don't work if i have more than 1 input

any suggestion please ?
thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a here-doc:

```
python myscript.py <<EOF
input line 1
input line 2
input line 3
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

**if python file is your own:**

1) Add this to the first line of your python file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
```

2) in shell make file executable:

```
chmod +x your_python_file.py
```

3) exec like a compiled program or bash script:

```
./your_python_file.py param1 param2 param3
```

Comment: sorry the python script is not mine :/

Comment: if it contains " #!/usr/bin/python" at the first line no matters yours or not yours. Otherwise u must pipe parameters into the file as they tell in other answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the argparse module that python provides: [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1)

Then you would write the following:

```
python myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Ah, I see, then that is definitely not an option.  :)